# Disable PCI sound card with udev

Tags: audio, udev, hardware, pci

**GP104 High Definition Audio Controller** which seems to be internal sound card in NVidia GeForce GTX 1070 which uses HDMI. It keeps popping up in various applications and sometimes messing with audio settings. I'd like to disable it with [udev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html) if possible.

`% lspci -vvvvvvvvv -d 10de:10f0`:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8599
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
        Region 0: Memory at c4080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 75W
                DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x16
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
                         10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Via message, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`% udevadm info -a /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1`:

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1':
    KERNEL=="card1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="sound"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{id}=="NVidia"
    ATTR{number}=="1"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1':
    KERNELS=="0000:01:00.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="snd_hda_intel"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x040300"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="2.5 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x10f0"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="40"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="17"
    ATTRS{link/clkpm}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ffff"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="8.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="707756"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="2820"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0xa1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8599"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x10de"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:01.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_cor}=="0"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_fatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{aer_rootport_total_err_nonfatal}=="0"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="2.5 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x4c01"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="121"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ffff"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="16.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/121}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="100"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="710587"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset_method}=="pm"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x01"
    ATTRS{secondary_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{subordinate_bus_number}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8694"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

My current attempt without success:

`% cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-nvidia-hdmi.rules`:

```
# Disable NVidia (vendor = 10de) GP104 HDMI audio (device = 10f0)
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ATTRS{vendor}=="10de", ATTRS{device}=="10f0" \
, RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

Kernel is Linux 6.2.0-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Feb 13 11:56:21 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

systemd 252 (252.5-1-manjaro)

Comment: FYI: you can add `OPTIONS="log_level=debug"` to the rule if you want to see debug information in `journalctl` or `dmesg` and to see if your rule even matches correct device(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked finally. `ATTRS{vendor}` and `ATTRS{device}` needed `0x` prefix and `remove` needed to be called instead of `authorized`. Basically the rule says "device was added, so remove it immediately".

`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-nvidia-hdmi.rules`:

```
# Disable NVidia (vendor = 0x10de) GP104 HDMI audio (device = 0x10f0)
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x10de", ATTRS{device}=="0x10f0" \
, RUN:="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > $sys$devpath/device/remove'"
```